# iOS Gmail shrinking font-size Mailing

Tags: ios, gmail, font-size, mailing

i have this email and in iOS Gmail app some part of the text (bullets copy) the app is shrinking (i don't know how to call it) the font-size or something, somehow knows how to fix this? i've been trying everything, please help me, Thanks!

Image:
https://ibb.co/cAJ9LH

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the Interface Builder of Xcode when you are working on a XIB or Storyboard file.

Have a look at this picture :

[image]

FYI, this links might probably be interesting for you.

- [Content Hugging and Compression resistance](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef)
- [View with intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html)